# Set primary key to existing table

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I have a table with 15 records. The table does not have any primary key constraint.

Now I want to set a primary key in the existing column. How can I set a column with primary key constraint to the existing table? Can somebody provide the query to alter the column?

It is for SQL server 2008.

Comment: The existing records should be unique before adding  Primary Key Constraint

Comment: This is a basic operation. Please try to use google before asking your question here. If you did, you would have found https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189039.aspx

Comment: Your question doens't show any research effort

Answer (score 2):

Alter syntax to add Primary Key Constraint to Existing Table...

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
ADD CONSTRAINT Primarykeyname PRIMARY KEY (column_name);
```

Specify the column name which one you want to set Primary Key. The values of the column should be unique.

Answer (score 1):

This is a runnable script. Try this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 'X'
              FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
              WHERE  CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'PRIMARY_KEY_NAME'
                     AND TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME')
  ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME
    ADD CONSTRAINT PRIMARY_KEY_NAME PRIMARY KEY(COLUMN_NAME_TO_BE_ADDED_AS_PRIMARY_KEY)

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the primary key is simple as in the below query, but column should be declared not null and if any existing values violate the primary key constraint, your query may not succeed.

```
create table
#temp
(
id int
)

ALTER TABLE #temp
ADD CONSTRAINT id_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

The above will fail. You have to run the below query first at least in SQL Server 2005.

```
alter table #temp
alter column id int not null
```